# How do I remove this weird geometry from my lens

Tags: modeling, rendering, geometry, reflection

so here is the issue guys:

[image]

is there any way I can remove that geometry effect from it, making it clear?

[image]

Comment: that is caused by your subdivision modifier, you need to correct you topology in those lenses to be "subdiv friendly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct so topology so that the central ngon is coplanar with its adjacent faces, otherwise the shading will be bad:

[image]